# How to show two rows from one record-ID with two different datefields and the same titlefield

Tags: rows, record

Hi there from a reasonable newbe on php and mysql. By looking and searching I have found out a lot, even got a nice working databasedriven website. But I have one problem which I can not get solved, even after a lot of searching and trying myself.
I show movietitles, dates and times of showing. I put all the info of the movie into one record per movie. There are movies that are being shown on two different dates and times. The record holds therefor TWO datefields (datum and datum2) (00.00.0000).
I get to present only the first (or last) date in one tablerow in stead of two seperate rows with the same title, one holding the first date and the second the other date. 
Do I make sense?
How do I get to do this?

I've tried the SELECT and tried IF's, ELSEIF's etc... but can anyone give me an working example? My example shows a workaround: both dates and times in one tablerow. This creates the problem that both dates disappear when the first date has passed. And you understand that I would like to keep the second date until it's time for it to 'go' aswell.
I love to hear from someone with thé solution.
I'm sorry I'm not allowed to post an image already to show my example. If you wanna take a look... (http://www.filmtheaterfanfare.nl/programma.php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database design is not flexible enough. What if a movie is shown a third time, will you add Datum3? Tables should not scale in the number of columns.

I would maintain two tables: Movies and Screenings. And there's a 1-to-n relation between them.

Then you can use a JOIN query to select the movie along with its latest screening date.

**EDIT:** The answer to your actual question is something like this:

```
SELECT
  Title,
  Date
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Title,
    Datum1 as Date
  FROM 
    Movies
  UNION
  SELECT
    Title,
    Datum2 as Date
  FROM
    Movies
  WHERE
    Datum2 IS NOT NULL
)
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Wow Ilya, thanks for the quick respons! The (lack of) flexiblity crossed my mind, but in our case we don't screen the movies lots of times. In rare occasions a movie will be shown a second time. We are not a regular cinema, every week we show one, different movie, therefor I designed the database this way. But... I'll have a try making a second db and joining them. But first I'm going to enjoy my holidays now.

Comment: But I keep the puzzle in my mind: and the question remains: is it possible to do what I wanted to do? Perhaps with something of an INNER JOIN, like repeating the selection a second time? I'm just wondering and learning... ;-)

Comment: Hi @BasVr, I edited the answer to include a more straighforward solution according to your existing table structure. Have a nice holiday!

Comment: I just found a tiny moment to try your solution. Needed a bit of tweaking for presentation, but YOU DID IT.